# Finding the basis for a kernel of a polynomial linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Say given the function:
$$ T: \mathbb R_{2}[t] \rightarrow \mathbb R_{1}[t]$$
$$ at^{2} + bt + c \rightarrow at + 2c - b $$

We were tasked to find the basis for the kernel of $T$ and $T(\mathbb R_2[t])$.

Where do I start? Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show you a general method to solve this kind of problems.
Take the canonical basis for $\mathbb R_2[x]$, which is $\mathcal C=\{x^2,x,1\}$ and find the images of its vectors.
I suggest you to consider the isomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb R_n[x]\longrightarrow\mathbb R^{n+1}$ to write polynomials as column vectors.

> Consider the polynomial $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, since we have an isomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb R_n[x]\longrightarrow \mathbb R^{n+1}$ we can map polynomials to column vectors.
> $$ax^2+bx+c \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c \end{pmatrix}$$
> Now we can find the images of the polynomials of any basis through $f$:
> $$p(x)=ax^2+bx+c \underset{\varphi}{\mapsto} \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c \end{pmatrix} \underset{f}{\mapsto} \begin{pmatrix}a\\2c-b \end{pmatrix}  $$
> Rmk: You work with column vectors to solve the exercise, but when you have to show a basis for your space of polynomials you have to change column vectors with polynomials.

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}\underset{f}{\mapsto} \begin{pmatrix}1\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0  \end{pmatrix}\underset{f}{\mapsto} \begin{pmatrix}0\\-1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} \underset{f}{\mapsto} \begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix}$$
Now we can write the matrix associated to the map $T$:
$$A:=\mathcal M_{\mathcal C}^{\mathcal C}(T)=\begin{pmatrix}1 && 0 &&0\\0&&-1 && 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
Studying the rank of $A$ you can find the linearly independent columns of the matrix which span $Im(T)=T(\mathbb R_2[x])$ and solving the system $(A|\underline 0)$ you get the vectors that generate $Ker(T)$. Remember that $3=dim(\mathbb R_2[x])=dim(Im(T))+dim(Ker(T))$.

Comment: I dont understand the part when you wrote the polynomials as column vectors? How did 3 rows become two rows? Is it because of how the linear transformation is defined? Also, could you check out my latest question? I'm trying to understand my prof's example to help me solve this problem.

Comment: You mean "Where do I start?"

Comment: Exactly lol. But its all good now. Got some help from other users.

Comment: I tried to be as clear as possible in the explanation of the correspondence between column vectors and polynomials because it is essential to solve these exercises... Anyway, I'm glad my answer helped you ;-)

Comment: Your answers are very clear and helpful! Its just that I lack the knowledge to understand them very well so i got some help from other users as well. Thanks for the help!